# Refreshing a chart control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

This one is driving me a bit crazy.  Any help gratefully received.  It's a simple program to receive temperature data from an Arduino based temp sensor, and display it in a graph control on a form.  The program works fine, and parses the temp data frame a treat.  However.....  the graph object doesn't refresh, and the whole point is to show the data over time.  I thought that the chart1.DataBind command that I put in forced a refresh.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express.  Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong very much appreciated.

```
// Start of program.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace serial_port_with_events_attempt_4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string RxString;
    int RxRead;
    int i;
    int RxDec1;
    int RxDec2;
    int RxDec3;
    float RxFloat;
    float RxFloat2;
    string locnString;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM8";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            buttonStart.Enabled = false;
            buttonStop.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        }
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            buttonStart.Enabled = true;
            buttonStop.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxRead = serialPort1.ReadByte();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));


    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (RxRead == 126)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            i = 0;
        }

        if (i< 23)
        {
            if (i == 7)
            {
                if (RxRead == 51) // 51 in this position means that the temp sensor is the one in the wooden box
                { 
                   textBox1.AppendText("Temperature in Nick's office = ");
                   locnString = ("Nick's office");
                }
            }

            if (i == 17)
            {
                RxDec1 = RxRead - 48; // Read the tens unit
            }

            if (i == 18)
            {
                RxDec2 = RxRead - 48; // Read the units
            }

            if (i == 20)
            {
                RxDec3 = RxRead - 49; // read the decimal
            }

            if (i == 22)
            {
                RxFloat = ((RxDec1 * 10) + RxDec2);
                RxFloat2 = RxDec3;
                RxFloat2 = RxFloat2 / 10;
                RxFloat = RxFloat + RxFloat2;
                RxString = RxFloat.ToString();
                if (RxFloat < 30 && RxFloat >20)
                {
                    // Put the value in the main text box if it is not corrupt, (checking if the range is reasonable
                textBox1.AppendText(RxString);  // Frig about to get the reads in the right format and added together
                    // Add a new line into the temperature database
                temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.Temp1TableAdapter temp1tableadapter = new temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.Temp1TableAdapter();
                temp1tableadapter.Insert(DateTime.Now, RxFloat, locnString);
                }
                // Delete any old data.
                temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.TempTableAdapter temp2tableadapter = new temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.TempTableAdapter();
                temp2tableadapter.DeleteTempQuery();
                 // The above two lines work, but I need to amend to select on date TODO

                chart1.DataBind();


            }
         }
            i=i+1;
     }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'temperature1DataSet.Temp' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tempTableAdapter.Fill(this.temperature1DataSet.Temp);

    }
    }
}
```

Cheers,

Nick James

Comment: Does it just 'not refresh' or doesn't it show any data points at all?

Comment: Hi TaW,

Thanks for the answer.  It shows the points but doesn't refresh.  Actually after a lot of googling, I've found the answer.  The DataBind command only resynchs to the query.  However,  the data "in" the query doesn't automatically respond to changes written to the underlying database.  I've had to rerun the query, and then run the DataBind command.  Now it works!

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize the chart was bound to a query. Should have inferred from `DeleteTempQuery`..